# Which timestamp is used for migrated questions for the Asking Days badges (curious/inquisitive/socratic)?

Tags: support, questions, badges, migration, asking-days-badges

If a question is migrated, which timestamp is used for the Asking Days badges (curious/inquisitive/socratic)? Original post timestamp or migration timestamp?

Comment: I believe it's the original post timestamp, since that's what gets recorded as the time the question was asked in the database.